# Angular 5 and Google App Engine (GAE)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I'm attempting to run an Angular 5 vanilla scaffolding (no customization, just testing) app on top of GAE but haven't had any success deploying it. I'm running into an `NGINX 502 Bad Gateway` error message. I've logged into the instance running the container to confirm that the `ng` is serving traffic locally and it is. After doing some research on here I see that people are tweaking their `app.yaml` files to work with handlers. However, the examples that I saw involved Python server, not Node. I'm leaving app.yaml very simple for this initial config, but I suspect I need more within it. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

**App.yaml:**

```
env: flex
runtime: nodejs
health_check:
  enable_health_check: False
```

**gcloud app read logs:**

```
 ** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:8080, open your browser on http://localhost:8080/ **
    Date: 2017-11-03T22:24:09.051Z
    Hash: 6b8111721660d89fdc61
    Time: 18180ms
    chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 5.79 kB [entry] [rendered]
    chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 19.8 kB [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 544 kB [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 33.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 7.02 MB [initial] [rendered]
    webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: An example of indicating handlers in node.js' app yaml, such as:

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: nothing.js

is to be found on the "ajessup/appengine-nodejs-example" page at: https://github.com/ajessup/appengine-nodejs-example/blob/master/app.yaml 

You may try debugging the 502 errors as suggested in a reply to the "Google App Engine 502 (Bad Gateway) with NodeJS" question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38012797/google-app-engine-502-bad-gateway-with-nodejs .

Comment: A step-by-step example of a similar app, for reference purposes, may be found at "Build a Node.js & Angular 2 Web App using Google Cloud Platform": https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-cardboard-viewer/index.html#0 .